# Debian cifs client suddenly break

Tags: debian, cifs, procfs, insmod

Previously, Debian mounted win10 cifs worked fine. Suddenly prompted "input/output error" when accessing the cifs file
See ls /proc/fs, cifs are missing

Even the nfs server failed to start.

I should not do anything to modify the system configuration, just copy the modinfo of ubuntu 10.10 to the debian 9 environment, the above phenomenon occurs after half an hour.

reload cifs.ko Fail

```
root@debian llg
$ modprobe cifs
...
do nothing
```

there are't cifs

```
$ ls -l /proc/fs/
总用量 0
dr-xr-xr-x 6 root root 0 3月  26 14:04 ext4
dr-xr-xr-x 6 root root 0 3月  26 14:04 jbd2
dr-xr-xr-x 2 root root 0 3月  26 14:04 nfsd
```

mount cifs server fail

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.51/project -o uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,noserverino,username=Administrator /mnt/cifs/project/
mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
```

```
root@debian llg
$ service nfs-kernel-server restart
A dependency job for nfs-server.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
```

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Starting Preprocess NFS configuration...
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Mounting NFSD configuration filesystem...
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: run-rpc_pipefs.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Failed to mount RPC Pipe File System.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS server.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: rpc-svcgssd.service: Job rpc-svcgssd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for RPC security service for NFS client and server.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: rpc-gssd.service: Job rpc-gssd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFSv4 ID-name mapping service.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: nfs-idmapd.service: Job nfs-idmapd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: run-rpc_pipefs.mount: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Started Preprocess NFS configuration.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Failed to mount NFSD configuration filesystem.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS Mount Daemon.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: Dependency failed for NFS server and services.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: nfs-server.service: Job nfs-server.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: nfs-mountd.service: Job nfs-mountd.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Mar 26 15:30:55 debian systemd[1]: proc-fs-nfsd.mount: Unit entered failed state.
```